# Bash - Renaming files with prefix before moving to single folder

Tags: bash, file-copying

Using bash how can I find all files in subdirectories with extension .txt, prefix the name with the directory name? Then move all those .txt files to a single folder in the current directory?

Example:

```
\subdirectory1\result1.txt  
\subdirectory1\result2.txt  
\subdirectory2\result1.txt  
\subdirectory2\result2.txt  
\subdirectory3\result1.txt  
\subdirectory3\result2.txt
```

I want to copy and prefix .txt files with the directory name and place them in a new directory such that the result is:

```
\newfolder\subdirectory1_result1.txt  
\newfolder\subdirectory1_result2.txt    
\newfolder\subdirectory2_result1.txt    
\newfolder\subdirectory2_result2.txt    
\newfolder\subdirectory3_result1.txt  
\newfolder\subdirectory3_result2.txt
```

Comment: add examples as well

Answer (score 1):

Given that your source files are in a directory hierarchy `src` and you want to move that to a destination directory `target`:

```
for f in $(find src -type f -name \*.txt) # select all files in src
do
    d=$(dirname $f | sed 's/\//-/g')   # extract directory part of path and subsitute / with -
    mv "$f" target/"$d"-$(basename $f) # move to target dir
done
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great for a single named folder. I made a few changes and now it does exactly what I was after.
`for i in *;
do
for f in $(find $i -type f -name \*.txt) # select all files in src
do
    d=$(dirname $f | sed 's/\//-/g')   # extract directory part of path and subsitute / with -
    cp "$f" target/"$d"-$(basename $f) # move to target dir
done
done`

Comment: @CarlKennedy I see, 1. you have several source directories (not just one) and 2. you want to copy, not to move. Hope you found my answer useful, nontheless.

Answer (score 1):

```
find <subdirectory> -name "*.txt" | awk -v newfolder="somefolder" -F\/ '{ system("mv "$(NF-1)$NF" "newfolder) }'
```

Using awk, list the files with the extension txt and then use awk field delimited using "/" to build a mv command executed through awk's system function. the passed variable newfolder contains the path to move the files to.

There are risks associated with injection with this awk solution but it is an option none the less.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using find and combining with mv

```
find <currentDirToSearch> -name "*.txt" -exec mv {} <destinationDir> \;
```

example

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec mv {} dirToMove \;
```